# Conditionally dropping duplicates from a data.frame

Tags: r, dataframe, subset

Im am trying to figure out how to subset my dataset according to the repeated value of the variable `s`, taking also into account the `id` associated to the row.

Suppose my dataset is:

```
dat <- read.table(text = "
        id     s          
        1      2     
        1      2     
        1      1      
        1      3     
        1      3     
        1      3     
        2      3     
        2      3     
        3      2     
        3      2", 
header=TRUE)
```

What I would like to do is, for each `id`, to keep only the first row for which `s = 3`. The result with `dat` would be:

```
        id     s          
        1      2     
        1      2     
        1      1      
        1      3         
        2      3         
        3      2     
        3      2
```

I have tried to use both `duplicated()` and `which()` for using `subset()` in a second moment, but I am not going anywhere. The main problem is that it is not sufficient to isolate the first row of the `s = 3` "blocks", because in some cases (as here between `id = 1` and `id = 2`) the 3's overlap between one id and another.. Which strategy would you adopt?

Comment: There are also duplicates in id=1 where s=2 and id=3 where s=2, do you want to keep these or remove them as well?

Comment: Yes, I want to keep them, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:

```
subset(dat, s != 3 | s == 3 & !duplicated(dat)) 
#    id s
# 1   1 2
# 2   1 2
# 3   1 1
# 4   1 3
# 7   2 3
# 9   3 2
# 10  3 2
```

Note that `subset` can be dangerous to work with (see [Why is `[` better than `subset`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9860090/in-r-why-is-better-than-subset)), so the longer but safer version would be:

```
dat[dat$s != 3 | dat$s == 3 & !duplicated(dat), ]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Also for the link

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea, I'd have to look at your data.